# Always print random values between ] -100 ; 100 [ as 2 digits before and 2 digits after the dot, python 3

Tags: python, formatting, format

I have **float numbers** between ] -100 ; 100 [ (100 not included) coming as inputs in my code (containing 400+ lines, which is why I simplify my question as most as I can).

Then I print one of these numbers in the middle of a string, using `.format()`.

I have found how to make this separately, but only with integer for leading zeros e.g. :

`number1 = 1
number2 =1.1
print('{:02d}'.format(number1))
print('{:.2f}'.format(number2))`

which would return me:

`01
1.10`

Now what I would like is to print a number such as `number2` as `01.10`. Is there a way to do so simply ?

I hope I have been clear and thank you in advance for your answers !

Comment: No, because when when I will receive numbers as 10.1, I would get 3 digits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python3.6+, you can use [literal string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/?). You can then use the standard [format specification](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to provide precision and left filling.

```
num = -1.123
print(f'Formatted number: {num: 06.2f}')
# prints: 'Formatted number: -01.12'

num = 6.789
print(f'Formatted number: {num: 06.2f}')
# prints: 'Formatted number: 06.79'
```

Inside the bracket:

- `'num'` is the variable to be formatted in.
- `' 06'` indicates that output should have width `6`, left filled with `0`, but that positive number are left-padded with a space instead of an extra `0`
- `'.2f'` indicates that you want a float with `2` digit of precision.

Answer (score 2):

To pad a number with zeros use

```
print('{: 06.2f}'.format(-99.3))
```

Explanation: the padding value `6` is the length of the whole number, including . and sign, a space after `:` indicates that an extra space should be used for positive numbers (see [the docs](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/format.html#sign))

Comment: Oh thank you ! I tried with `{:02.2f}` and as I saw no differences I came here. Now I understand why !